# Unit test: How to test if rails migrations being called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a method that runs rails migrations. (Part of installation automation of a RAILS app).

I want to test whether this method calls the rails migrations. I don't want to check the results of running migrations because that would be testing rails migrations. Unit testing this method implies I want to check whether my method in turn called rails migration or not.

How to unit test this method in rspec?

```
def run_migrations
  system('bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development')
end
```

Comment: You're trying to migrate one environment (development) from another environment (test)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would stub that call and check if that stub was called.

```
before do
  allow(Kernel).to receive(:system).and_return(true)
end

it 'runs migrations' do
  instance.run_migrations # or however you trigger such that method to be called

  expect(Kernel).to have_received(:system).with('bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development').once
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`system('bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development')` return `true`, when it works. So `expect(run_migrations).to eq true` will be enough.

Comment: I want to assert whether `db:migrate` was called! 
An expectation this method being it true won't ensure that migrations were actually called ? Correct me if I am wrong. (Think it the TDD way ! )

Comment: @AbhishekSah `system` returns true if the command gives zero exit status, false for non zero exit status. Returns nil if command execution fails. So you see if happens something wrong. But also you can check your migration version by `ActiveRecord::Migrator.current_version`